# Block spam referer and subdomains from htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm blocking spam referer with this code. This works for simple-share-buttons.com, the problem is that I'm still receiving visits from sites like site22.simple-share-buttons.com. Is there any way I can block also the subdomain rather than adding them all in htaccess?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} simple-share-buttons\.com [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

Comment: The directive you already have would block subdomains as well - providing the HTTP Referer is set appropriately (but presumably it is if you are able to see this in your logs?).

Comment: @w3d thanks for your reply. htaccess is set as I wrote, but still today, I received 33 visits from site33.simple-share-buttons.com

Comment: Are you sure that this is actually working for `simple-share-buttons.com` (no subdomain)? Because it's actually impossible that this code would catch one and not the other - providing the HTTP referer is actually set in both cases.

Comment: Where do you see the referer logged - in your _server_ access logs? You can test these directives with CURL or similar (or examine your server access logs in real time).

Comment: Google analytics, my site is in HTTPS, can this change?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following method

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://([^.]+\.)*simple-share-buttons\.com [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

or

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} site22.simple-share-buttons.com [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

if you still having traffic from specific domain. it is using your Google Analytics Code to recreate fake information and sending that directly to Google Analytics.

So you cannot do anything with {HTTP_REFERER} to stop it.

You can see more information about [this subject here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29232903/rewrite-rule-not-filtering-referral-spam-correctly-anymore/29241058#29241058) and how to solve it.

thanks

Comment: This is really no different from the code given in the question, except this is even more restrictive. (?)

Comment: @Christos if I change my analytics account, I should solve the problem right?

Comment: Yes.  but in the future you may face the same problem.  This in not a solution. read here: (http://www.analyticsedge.com/2015/01/advanced-segment-eliminate-spam-referrals/) how to put filters in your analytics it is not dificult. Also here: (http://viget.com/advance/removing-referral-spam-from-google-analytics)

Comment: Hello @ChristosPentakalos, thanks again for your reply. I've posted a follow-up of the situation here as it isn't about programming: http://superuser.com/questions/895219/google-analytics-spam-referral
Question is: if my site is not public, and no-one knows the google analytics but me, how can they alter my analytics stats...?

Comment: They dont need to now your analytics code. They dont hitting you. They are just hitting radomly google analytics ids. The problem is in google. The best is to put filters as i said before. Go to the link in my 1 answer and follow method 1. Your problem will be solved